# Can perfMon be used to understand why a page become much slower?

Tags: networking, performance-monitor, perfmon

In my department, we have two sites, say Site 1 and Site 2. Site 2 is in backup mode (so no traffic goes into there at all, but running).
Our website suddenly becomes slow this week.

As there was no code deployment, this is what:
1. Grabbed the live code to run on my machine and pointing to the same database server on live. This shows that the code is running fast.
2. Run the same code on site 2 (the backup site with no traffic). This shows that the code is running slow.
3. Run the code on site 1 (the live site with traffic). This shows that the code is runnning as slow as site 2 (the one without traffic).

For me, this means that the code is not problem, and the problem is on some IT related thing (maybe server or maybe some network issue).

Can PerfMon be helpful in this scenario?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What is slow about the site?  Is it calls back to the server?  Is it the client side code running in the browser?

Comment: I put lots of log into the code, turned out that everything is slower. For example, after the data is loaded, I do some math aggregation, and even that is twice slower than my machine. This math calculation has nothing to do with network, so somehow the VM is slower than before now.

Comment: Are site 1 and site 2 on the same host? Different hosts? If different same rack or different rack?